# Loop through + update DB with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

I have been reading and trying different things, but I just can't seem to get the hang of Jquery.

Here's the context: with PHP, I get ten random items from my database. I hit the start button, one of the items shows. Users can then rate the item (like or dislike), that result gets updated in the DB and the next one shows. After rating ten items, the app resets and you can start again by hitting the start button again.

Now I also need to get this working with jQuery or javaScript so the user doesn't have to refresh all the time. I have no idea how to get started. I know you all say 'read the documentation', but honestly I have and I just need some pointers so I can figure it out.

hit the start button

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="start" />
```

variable in php file fills this

```
<article>
<header>
<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['videos'][$_GET['id']]['title'].' - '. $first.'.'?></h1>
<h2>Originally by <?php echo $_SESSION['videos'][$_GET['id']]['artist'] ?></h2>
</header>
...
<video width="205" height="319"  controls>
<source src="assets/videos/<?php echo $_SESSION['videos'][$_GET['id']]['video'] ?>"type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

rate with these buttons + redirected to next random item in array of ten

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="like" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="dislike" />
```

This all works fine, but how do I get it working with jQ/Js? What I am thinking: Link a click event to the start button, prevent the default. But then what? I need to load ten random items from the database, append the first one to the body, then add a click event to the like/dislike buttons, prevent the default and update the database without resfreshing.

Anyone has some pointers? Struggling here...

Thanks

Comment: Try finding some [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) examples. You should be able to do what you want with relative ease.

Comment: thank you for your swift response. I did look into Ajax, but I'm new to it (as I am to jq). Is there any particular example you could refer me to? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

here is a basic flow of this kind of thing but your implementation could vary however you want

```
$('input[value="like"]').click(function(){
    var video_id = //however you want to supply video_id here
    $.post('likehandler.php',{id:video_id}, function(result){
        //result is just whatever likehandler.php echos to the screen (usually json_encoded data)
        //your php page would mark the video with the $_POST[id], and then grab a new random video 
        //result.next_video is a json_encoded object from your php page
        if(result.next_video){
            //if your ajax response contains a new video, remove the old, and replace it with the new
            $('video').remove();
            $('body').append("<video width... src='assets/videos/"+result.next_video.video+"' type...">);
        }
    }, 'json');
});

//possible example of likehandler.php
    <?php
        $video_id = $_POST['id'];
        //update video with one more vote in database

       $next_video = //get a random video from database
       echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success","next_video"=>$next_video));
    ?>
```

this is definitely not a copy and paste answer, but its the basic flow, and could point you to how this works.